# I want to convert php string of form {1}1{2}3{3}6 to php array

Tags: php, arrays

I get the format of this `{1}1{2}3{3}6` string in php and I want to make the numbers in curly braces to be the indexes of array and the value stored on the indexes will be the value after the curly braces. So that I can easily apply `foreach` to enter the values in database.

Output Array should be like:

```
array([1]=>1,[2]=>3,[3]=>6)
```

Comment: The string is $str = "{1}1{2}3{3}6"; ? is it like that ?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I am getting the product options id in curly braces and product options values id after the curly braces end. So i wanted to convert thi to array so i save it in database 

Product Options         Product Options Id
1                                1
2                                3
3                                6

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = [];
$data = '{1}1{2}3{3}6';
preg_match_all('/\{(\d+)\}\s*(\d+)/', $data, $m);
foreach ($m[1] as $i => $key) {
    $result[$key] = $m[2][$i];
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.
Just changed this for me
$result = array();

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with regex "Regular expression" as follows:

```
<?php
$string="{1}1{2}3{3}6";

//Define the regex
$regex = "/{([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)}\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

//Temporary array to store the data
$arry = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $key => $value){
        $arry[$value] = $matches[2][$key];
}
var_dump($arry);
?>
```

**[Proof of concept]**

> array(3) {
>
> [1]=>   string(1) "1"
> [2]=>   string(1) "3"
> [3]=>  string(1) "6"
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$str = '{1}1{2}3{3}6';
$arr = explode("}", substr(str_replace("{", "}", $str), (strlen($str)-1)*-1));
$arr = array_map(function ($v){ global $arr; return $arr[$v+1]; }, array_flip(array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(array_filter(array_keys($arr), function ($v){ return !($v & 1); })))));
```